# vs2012 crystal reports vs fast reports

Tags: visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports-xi, fastreport

I am hoping that someone can give me advice on the following. My company is in the process of changing over from delphi XE2 to VS2012. In delphi we used Fast Reports but now that we are moving over I would like to know which is better Fast Reports.net or crystal Reports. I am hoping someone can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 1):

Please do yourself a favor and search google for "I hate Crystal Reports". The sheer number and ferocity of complaints is astounding. From absentee customer service and legacy black box licensing to useless documentation and lack of flexibility, I'm surprised this product is still around. Use anything else you can, we roll our own reports via the web.

Answer (score 1):

We abandoned Crystal Reports years ago and we are using the [ReportDesigner](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/) included in Visual Studio. It's a powerful tool but I recommended to stick with Fast Reports if it covers all your needs (also consider other aspects: i.e. report conversion).